# AsyncTask always throw NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

I am developing LBS based app in 1.6 version and it is running absolutely fine in it. Earlier its also run fine in updated version like 2.2 & 2.3.3. But now suddenly it starts giving me null pointer exception in AsyncTask class which i have used for background processes. Here is my code snippet with Error Log.

```
public class AndroidLocationActivity extends Activity {

public String provider;
public double latitude, longitude = 0;
public LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
public LocationManager locationManager;
public CurrentPositionTask getCurrentLocation;
public long time=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    setCriteria();
    runAsyncTask();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    time = 0;
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}

public void setCriteria() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider - " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (provider == null) {
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    }
}


public void runAsyncTask() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (getCurrentLocation == null) {
        getCurrentLocation = new CurrentPositionTask(AndroidLocationActivity.this); 
    }

    if (getCurrentLocation != null) {
        getCurrentLocation.execute("Searching for Location");   
    }
}

public boolean checkConnection()
{
    //ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()&& conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} 


class CurrentPositionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidLocationActivity.this);
    Location location = new Location(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
    Context context;

    public CurrentPositionTask(Context mContext) {
        this.context = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        time = location.getTime();
        Toast.makeText(AndroidLocationActivity.this, String.valueOf(time), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (checkConnection()) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            Dialog.setMessage("Searching for Location");
            Dialog.show();
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Internet is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        if (time >= 100000) {
            latitude = 0;
            longitude = 0;
        }

        while (latitude == 0 && longitude == 0) {               
            /*latitude = (float) (location.getLatitude());
            longitude = (float) (location.getLongitude());*/                
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(AndroidLocationActivity.this, "Location Floats:- " + latitude + "," + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (Dialog != null && Dialog.isShowing()) {
            Dialog.dismiss();
            time=0;
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(AndroidLocationActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), HomeMenuActivity.class);
            homeIntent.putExtra("lat", latitude);
            homeIntent.putExtra("lng", longitude);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

}

**Error Log:-**

```
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidlocation/com.androidlocation.AndroidLocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.location.Location.set(Location.java:119)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.location.Location.<init>(Location.java:112)
**12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):   at com.androidlocation.AndroidLocationActivity$CurrentPositionTask.<init>(AndroidLocationActivity.java:84)**
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at com.androidlocation.AndroidLocationActivity.runAsyncTask(AndroidLocationActivity.java:60)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at com.androidlocation.AndroidLocationActivity.onCreate(AndroidLocationActivity.java:31)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-04 16:59:04.848: E/AndroidRuntime(4165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
```

3error which i got from log, 1 in calling the runAsyncTask() method, 2 at the time of creating object of async task class and 3rd at the time of initializing the location variable in asynctask class.

Please if anybody has any idea about this please help me to solved it out. Thanks...

Comment: doInBackGround is supposed to do the heavy tasks. As far as I see most of the heavy tasks are in preExecute. doinBackGround runs in a worker thread. Is it supposed to update the members defined on the UI thread directly?

Comment: No i am not updating UI thread directly....And i am calling requestUpdates method in preExecute as if i call it from doInBackground it gives me error.

Comment: Anyone has any idea about this error? Please kindly help me if anyone knows anything about this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Location location = new Location(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider))` can be null, try make a null check before:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        time = location.getTime();
...
```

Comment: Thanks Michele for your quick response. Let me try your suggestion hope it works....

Comment: Michele i try to check it but it still not running and giving me null pointer, but i change from this

Location location = new Location(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
to

Location location = new Location(provider); 

but then its not giving me the location...

Comment: Hello Michele, did you get any idea to resolve this problem? Please help me if you have any idea because i am unable to resolve this.

Comment: i dont know what the problem is. When there is no LastKnownLocation eg. returning null, you have to wait for the gps fix to get a location in your LocationListener.