# Progressdialog in AsyncTask causes NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm trying to create a `ProgressDialog` but all my efforts failed with a NPE. I have seen previous posts such as [AsyncTask always throw NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375040/asynctask-always-throw-nullpointerexception) and tried to adopt the provided solutions but to no avail. For testing I created a really simple app with one button that should start the `ProgressDialog.`
Here is the `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new ProgressAsyncTask(context).execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is the AsyncTask class file (it's a separate file entirely):

```
    public class ProgressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Short, Void>{

    private Context context_2;
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context_2);
    short max=100;

    public ProgressAsyncTask(Context context_1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context_2=context_1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setTitle("Test");
        dialog.setMax(max);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Bitte warten");
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (short i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            publishProgress(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Short...shorts) {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(shorts[0]);

    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Here is my logcat output:

```
07-29 18:53:31.373: E/Trace(14666): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at de.emwe.progressdialog.ProgressAsyncTask.<init>(ProgressAsyncTask.java:21)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at de.emwe.progressdialog.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:26)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-29 18:53:34.212: E/AndroidRuntime(14666):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I assume there is a problem with the context, but I'm not sure how to approach it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, you don't need to call an `AsyncTask` constructor with a `Context` as long as it's in the same class, you can just say `new ProgressAsyncTask().execute();` You don't need a constructor.

Now, to minimize on `Context` issues, you can do the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    private class ProgressAsync extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> { //Fill these in with classes
        ...
    }
}
```

And your calling line will be:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ProgressAsyncTask().execute(/*An instance of type Params*/);
}
```

**EDIT**

Now, I saw where you went wrong:
This line:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context_2);
```

is the problem. You're initializing the dialog BEFORE `context_2` is initialized, so it's going to throw a `NullPointerException` if you try to do anything with it.

What you should do is:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
public ProgressAsyncTask(Context context_1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    context_2=context_1; //NOT NEEDED! See below.
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context_1); //You can just eliminate context_2 and use context_1;
}
```

Comment: My AsnycTask is in a separate class file without Activity. To create the ProgressDialog I need context.

Comment: The AsnyTask is I set up: public class ProgressAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Short, Void> I neend no parameter passed to the doInBackground method - first void. Pregress is defined as Short becaus the maximum value is 100 and I need no result back - again Void.

Comment: What you would do is place the `ProgressAsync` in `MainActivity` as I have shown above

Comment: I saw where you went wrong and updated my answer. This will fix your problem, but in my opinion, `AsyncTasks` should be placed within the calling class, as to minimize `Context` issues.

Comment: the provided code is a testing example, in my real project I wll need the very same progressdialog/Asynctask in several Activities. Thats the reason why I need to define it in an own class file.

Comment: Thanks, you solution worked. No I will continue with my real project (unfortunately much more complex, dynamically getting context etc.